# Read the orientation change from another activity

Tags: android, orientation

I made a button that users can change the orientation in landscape or portrait.
my first activity doing well with the rotation.

This is the code what I use to write in shared-preferences:

```
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            editor.putInt("orientation",
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            editor.putInt("orientation",
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        editor.commit();
```

And here is when I read from it:

```
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int orientation = sharedpreferences.getInt("orientation", -1);
    if (orientation != -1) {
        setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }
```

And here is the onSave and onRestore:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (outState == null) {
        outState = new Bundle();
    }
    outState.putInt("currentOrientation",
            Integer.valueOf(currentOrientation));
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    currentOrientation = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentOrientation");

}
```

Every thing works fine except when I'm going to another activity and my app is crashing there.

Its giving me this error:

**E/AndroidRuntime(1213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.com.test/com.com.test.Test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class**

My question is that, how can I read the **sharedpreferences** in my **Second activity** from my **First activity**?

**Edit:**
Here is my second Activity

```
public class Test extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you call `editor.commit()` to write the changes to disk?

Comment: Yes I did, I don't have problem with my first activity its writing and reading. :)